How should the current value be when choosing a ferrite bead
We use ferrite beads with BK2125LM252-T code in projects. In the datasheet it says 200 mA rated current. but we draw a current between 2-3 A from the line to which this bead is connected. How does this happen? Shouldn't it be overturned? Is this practice right?
We have run hundreds of circuits with a 200 mA ferrite bead.
if this is wrong, how do I choose the right bead?
Is it enough to choose a 3 A bead?

Is the 2-3 A a continuous current draw, or brief pulses?

Seems unlikely to me that your supply would be capable of providing the necessary voltage such that 3 amps is actually going through your 2.5k (nominal resistance) bead.  Are you certain the circuit is acting the way you describe?  What are your measurements?  Post a schematic.

What's the purpose of the ferrite beads in your circuit?

@ChrisKnudsen The bead in question has 750 mΩ of DC resistance. The headline spec for ferrite beads is high-frequency impedance, usually specified at 100 MHz.

There are two relevant ratings for the maximum current.

Heating and voltage drop
RF performance


The ferrite bead will have a residual resistance, probably in the tens to hundreds of mΩ. This will cause an IR voltage drop to the components being supplied, and I2R heating in the bead. Measure the voltage to the downstream components, and make sure the bead is not desoldering itself.

The ferrite core of the bead will become saturated at some current, dropping its permeability dramatically. This means the low frequency (sub 1 MHz) inductance will fall by a large factor, along with the lossy RF impedance. Your design may need this high impedance to meet filtering goals. Measure its RF performance.


Even if your design currently meets its DC and RF performance goals, there is a chance that the ferrite bead you are buying may change, while keeping the same part number, and meeting the same published minimum specifications, and now fail to meet your requirements.
It's generally best to design equipment so that components run within their published specifications.

Thank you Nail_UK

The ferrites will have rated impedance if they are used at rated current. If you increase the actual current the impedance will fall. This will mean that your ferrite will act more like 0R resistor.

Source: Ferrite Beads Demystified (https://www.analog.com/en/resources/analog-dialogue/articles/ferrite-beads-demystified.html
Actually, you can see on the graphs above that impedance reduces with current anyway. If you go over rated current you will go very low with impedance and there is no point in using the ferrite.
I really strongly suggest using ferrites with the right rated current, acutally use ferrites with rated currents higher than actual current drawn if possible.
You can read about this here:

It was very revealing. Thank you very much.

For this Taiyo Yuden part in the BK series, the rated current of 0.2A is specified as the current where temperature of the part is increased by 20 degrees C.
Also the impedance at rated current is allowed to change by +/- 30%.
Running it at 2-3 A would only not make it saturate beyond the specs for impedance and be inefficient for reducing the high frequency ripples, but it would also drop 1.5V to 2.25A max, dissipating 3 to 6.75 watts max, and overheating.
The Precautions document for using the product states that operating current including any inrush currents must not exceed the rated current. They don't say why, other than excess current may reduce the inductance due to saturation.
If you intend to pass 3A, you need a ferrite rated for 3A. It needs to handle the DC current without damage. If you are only interested in passing 3A and have so far ignored the ferrite bead being saturated and unable to filter, maybe a resistor would suffice instead. A 0 ohm link resistor or just remove any component.
